# How to pass custom parameter which contains global enviroment-variable to ruby script in JenkinsCI?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, environment-variables, parameter-passing

I configured parameterized job in Jenkins with string parameter DEPLOYMENT_ADDRESS - default value is some/path/${SVN_REVISION}.

SVN_REVISION is enviroment-variable available to shell scripts in Jenkins.

When I call ruby script

```
ruby file_generator.rb -d $DEPLOYMENT_ADDRESS
```

In console output this looks like

```
ruby file_generator.rb -d 'some/path/${SVN_REVISION}'
```

and param value inside my script is 'some/path/${SVN_REVISION}'. But I need somthing like 'some/path/123'.

What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE>>

Code example, where I parse parameters:

```
require 'optparse'

option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  executable_name = File.basename($PROGRAM_NAME)
  opts.banner = "Usage: #{executable_name} [options] output_file_name"
    opts.on('-d DEPLOYMENT_ADDRESS', 'The deployment address where the file will reside') do |deployment_address|
        options[:deployment_address] = deployment_address
    end
end

option_parser.parse!

output_file_name = ARGV.shift

puts options[:deployment_address]     # => /some/path/${SVN_REVISION}. But I need somthing like /some/path/123
```

Comment: If someone interested I resolved the problem by separating parameter from environment variable. So I have DEPLOYMENT_ADDRESS with value 'some/path/' and SVN_REVISION environment variable which I access from script like ENV["SVN_REVISION"].

Comment: You failed to show an accurate code example of what you are using. Without that we're guessing.

Comment: Added some code example above.

Answer (score 0):

Without the required example code it's difficult to say for sure, but I'm going to guess that you used a single quote to delimit your string, instead of the needed double-quotes or the incorrect embedded variable flag.

Try:

```
"some/path#{SVN_VERSION}"
```